# Is it common practice that vendors put own root certificates on customer devices?

Tags: certificates, trust, root

At work, we are deploying a new VoIP solution, and as part of that, we are supposed to install a custom root certificate on our computers and mobile devices.  The manufacturer of  that VoIP solution has the private key to that.  The certificate is suitable for e.g. validating TLS connections.

While I have no reason not to trust the external company, I’ve never needed to do something like this and find this insecure (and unnecessary, for that matter).  Concretely, I’ve never touched my `/etc/ssl/certs` except for adding self-signed test certs.

I ask whether this is common practice out there?  Are there situations where one has got to install a new root CA, controlled by an external vendor, on work and/or private devices, and this is considered acceptable in the security community?

Comment: I would ask if it would be possible to supply your own certificates. If the answer is no, look for someone sane...

Comment: So a VoIP manufacturer couldn't pay to get a real cert? That's awfully suspicious. I'd be asking a 100 questions about their security measures around their key management and CA security. If their CA gets popped, your TLS security goes out the window. All solved by ... buying a real cert. The cost of that would be far less than setting up the security and governance to secure their own CA...

Comment: *"The manufacturer of that VoIP solution has the private key to that."* - Is what you describe your understanding or is that what the vendor says? Is is really a globally installed new root CA or is this one installed in some different path and only used by the application? If globally: can the vendor explain what this certificate is used for and why it is necessary to be provided and controlled by the vendor?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich There has been a custom root cert created.  It is stored on servers of our company, and the VoIP vendor has access to its private key.  I have no information so far why this is technically necessary. I just ask here whether you know of such procedures, and that in some cases, this makes sense.

Comment: *"I have no information so far why this is technically necessary. I just ask here whether you know of such procedures, and that in some cases, this makes sense."* - it is really tricky to provide a useful answer with only the few real facts, i.e. no information what this CA is exactly for, where it  all gets trusted (globally or application specific), why the vendor requires this, role of the vendor in the infrastructure (product vs. service offering) ...  With more facts the answer might range from not common at all to not unusual in such specific case.

Comment: Request for detailed information is on its way, and I will enrich my question accordingly.